# AC to DC conversion: is this an appropriate implementation?

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener, ac-dc

I understand that a 20v AC converter supplies 20V RMS AC. I wish to convert this to 20v DC and so have drawn up a schematic for this which includes: the AC to DC conversion, regulation, smoothing, and noise reduction.

I am looking for *constructive* feedback please.

If a part of it won't work can you please identify which part and why; extra points for how to improve it.

Schematic:
[image]

I am reletively new to electronics and come from a computer science background so please excuse my ignorance where appropriate.

Comment: Curiously I also come from computer science background. I found it very enlightening to play with such circuits that I drew up in a simulator. [Falstad](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/) back then, LTspice today.

Comment: @anrieff is LTspice lightweight and downloadable? as I am on very limited data.

Comment: Otherwise, besides "try it in a simulator" suggestion, I'm wondering why do you use a discrete implementation for the regulation part, why not LM7820 and 7920 ICs? This is not only more in partcount, zeners have a significant temperature coefficient too.

Comment: We need a more detailed spec. What load current and how much ripple is acceptable?

Comment: @equave, LTspice XVII in particular, and under Wine, since I'm on Linux. It's downloadable, about 80MB uncompressed.

Comment: hmm, well I hve myself the challenge to not use any pre made chips so that I learn more from it. however I am beginning to want to cave on that more as time goes on lol.

Comment: Very important is what current you think to draw out of this. You have only a single regulator transistor fed by ~100?K. Also your 20V zeners are totally wrongly placed and connected. Even if you regulate to 20V you suddenly add a diode which causes 0.6V drop.  For learning this may be good but I agree with @anrieff for usage I would get a regulator IC.

Comment: load current about 0.45A max on each of the positive and negative lines

Comment: so drop the diode? and what changes would I make to place the zener in a better location?

Comment: Put it on the base of your regulator transistor and drop the feedback transistor. You actuality want a 19.4V zener. With 20V the output will be 0.6V too high due to the Base-Emitter voltage .  But in that case I would keep the diode in the output line as that will drop the voltage back to about 20V. Not ideal but close.

Comment: or should I regulate to 20.6 to preempt the voltage drop?

Comment: ah then I would need stronger zeners that can take more wattage ....

Comment: This is a 100 year old rectifier design with a 50 y.o. regulator design, while still seen and occasionally useful, it would be like starting to code with fortran77 in 2019, unless you are hacking a guitar amp, it seems silly to start with heavy iron designs, an SMPS is extremely relevant.

Comment: I say this as someone as a CS background  now a working EE who started with these types of supply  circuits, it's not really the best pedagogy IMO in terms of being relevant for contemporary professional and hobby EE.

Answer (score 0):

Designing Power Supplies looks simple but has more complexity than it looks with peak current inverse to the ripple voltage and heat loss in addition to the inefficiency of linear regulators.

Then there are the safety aspects of AC supplies for power line transient protection and heat rise on active components in an enclosed box.

Today SMPS can be as low as 15 cents per watt and you can cascade two to make a bipolar center grounded split supply.

> This is the era when it is better to learn more useful skills and make wise decisions on make vs buy.

But can learn alot about the critical need to balance loads in  split transformers in [simulators.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.00009999999999999999%203.046768661252054%2054%205%2050%0Av%20208%2032%20208%20-32%200%201%2050%20340%200%200%200.5%0Aw%2096%2064%20208%2032%200%0A169%20208%20-32%20304%20-32%200%201%200.15%200.23108464812777746%200.43309778886562245%200.44010794675637%200.95%0Aw%2096%200%20208%20-32%200%0Ap%2096%200%2096%2064%201%201%0Ap%20528%20-32%20576%2064%201%204%0Ar%20528%20-32%20528%2064%200%2040%0Aw%20304%20-32%20336%20-32%200%0Aw%20304%2032%20304%20160%200%0Ag%20304%200%20320%2016%200%0Ad%20336%20-32%20384%20-32%202%20default%0Ad%20336%20160%20384%20-32%202%20default%0Ad%20384%20160%20336%20-32%202%20default%0Ad%20384%20160%20336%20160%202%20default%0Ar%20384%20-32%20416%20-32%200%200.1%0Al%20416%20-32%20448%20-32%200%200.0011%200.4401076038835272%0Ac%20448%20-32%20448%2080%200%200.01%2042.39454094892031%0Ar%20528%20160%20528%2064%200%2040%0Ag%20528%2064%20496%2064%200%0Aw%20448%20-32%20528%20-32%203%0Aw%20528%20160%20448%20160%202%0Al%20416%20160%20448%20160%200%200.001%20-0.4330974459928539%0Ar%20384%20160%20416%20160%200%200.1%0Ar%20448%2080%20448%20160%200%200.1%0Aw%20304%20160%20336%20160%200%0Aw%20576%2064%20528%2064%200%0Aw%20576%20160%20528%20160%200%0Ap%20528%20-32%20576%20160%201%204%0Ao%200%2064%200%204099%20640%2012.8%200%202%200%203%0Ao%206%2064%200%2012546%2021.33376234578526%200.0001%201%202%206%203%0Ao%2017%2064%200%2012546%2021.210837817572507%200.0001%202%202%2017%203%0Ao%2016%2064%200%204354%2080%200.1%203%202%2016%203%0Ao%205%2064%200%204354%2080%200.1%204%201%0Ao%2018%2064%200%204353%200.0000762939453125%200.0125%205%202%2018%203%0A)